# Handling commas when using a namespace PREFIX in a Sparql WHERE clause

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, virtuoso

I am trying to query the `skos:broader` property for the DBPedia category "Diseases_of_oral_cavity,_salivary_glands_and_jaws". This category is available at the following URI:
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Diseases_of_oral_cavity,_salivary_glands_and_jaws

The following query provides the desired output:

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 

SELECT ?broaderCategory
WHERE {
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Diseases_of_oral_cavity,_salivary_glands_and_jaws> skos:broader ?broaderCategory
}
```

The requirement is to query the `skos:broader` property for several categories using Python code and a Sparql wrapper. I am trying to make the code more readable by defining a `PREFIX` for all DBPedia category URIs and using it in the `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
PREFIX dbpcat: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:> 
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> 

SELECT ?broaderCategory
WHERE {
    dbpcat:Diseases_of_oral_cavity,_salivary_glands_and_jaws skos:broader ?broaderCategory
}
```

The second query returns a syntax error at the ',' in the category name. Replacing the comma with escape sequences (hex-unicode and html) hasn't helped. And, using a string literal (`dbc:"[category]"` and `dbc:'''[category]'''`) isn't correct syntax either.

How should the comma be handled in this case?

Comment: As @AKSW noted, this does appear to be a bug.  I've reported it internally. You can get updates and raise priority by reporting via [project issues on github](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/) and/or the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/); if using Commercial Edition, an [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp) may (also) be appropriate. (ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is based in the [W3C recommendation for Turtle](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/):

Some special characters are not allowed in the local part of prefixed IRIs. According to the [section about IRIs](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#sec-iri)

> Prefixed names are a superset of XML QNames. They differ in that the local part of prefixed names may include:
>
> 1. leading digits, e.g. `leg:3032571` or `isbn13:9780136019701`
> 2. non leading colons, e.g. `og:video:height`
> 3. reserved character escape sequences, e.g. `wgs:lat\-long`

In addition, the section about [escape sequences](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#sec-escapes) gives us more insights:

> %-encoded sequences are in the character range for IRIs and are explicitly allowed in local names. These appear as a '%' followed by two hex characters and represent that same sequence of three characters. These sequences are not decoded during processing. A term written as http://a.example/%66oo-bar in Turtle designates the IRI http://a.example/%66oo-bar and not IRI http://a.example/foo-bar. A term written as `ex:%66oo-bar` with a prefix `@prefix ex: <http://a.example/>` also designates the IRI http://a.example/%66oo-bar.

### Update (according to comment below)

As @AndyS pointed out,

> reserved character escape sequences consist of a '\' followed by one of ~.-!$&'()*+,;=/?#@%_ and represent the character to the right of the '\'.

So escaping with `\` works for commas, i.e. you can write `\,`. Unfortunately, this still fails in the Virtuoso Web UI with

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 0: Bad character '\' (0x5c) in SPARQL expression at '\'
```

So that should be a bug.

Comment: @AndyS Thanks for the hint, you're right I updated my answer.