# Comma error while searching on SPARQL, DBpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper

While performing the query giving error, syntax error at ',' before '_New_South_Wales'.

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX grs: <http://www.georss.org/georss/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

SELECT ?label ?country ?isPartOf ?_type ?capital ?lcity ?geopoint
WHERE {
        { dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales rdfs:label ?label  .  FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), "en"))}
          UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales dbo:country ?country} }
          UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales dbo:isPartOf ?isPartOf}}
          UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales <http://purl.org/linguistics/gold/hypernym> ?_type}}
          UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales dbo:capital ?capital}}
          UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales dbo:largestCity ?lcity}}
          UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales grs:point ?geopoint}}
  }
```

complete error report is as follows.

> Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 21: syntax error at ',' before '_New_South_Wales' SPARQL query: #output-format:application/sparql-results+json define input:default-graph-uri PREFIX owl: PREFIX xsd: PREFIX rdfs: PREFIX rdf: PREFIX foaf: PREFIX dc: PREFIX : PREFIX dbpedia2: PREFIX dbpedia: PREFIX skos: PREFIX dbo: PREFIX dbp: PREFIX dbr: PREFIX grs: PREFIX geo: SELECT ?label ?country ?isPartOf ?_type ?capital ?lcity ?geopoint WHERE { { dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales rdfs:label ?label . FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), "en"))} UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales dbo:country ?country} } UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales dbo:isPartOf ?isPartOf}} UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales ?_type}} UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales dbo:capital ?capital}} UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales dbo:largestCity ?lcity}} UNION{OPTIONAL{dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales grs:point ?geopoint}} }

here is the link where you can test this query yourself.
[snorql](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=PREFIX%20dbo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20dbp%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fproperty%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20dbr%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20grs%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.georss.org%2Fgeorss%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20PREFIX%20geo%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2003%2F01%2Fgeo%2Fwgs84_pos%23%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SELECT%20%3Flabel%20%3Fcountry%20%3FisPartOf%20%3F_type%20%3Fcapital%20%3Flcity%20%3Fgeopoint%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20dbr%3AEraring%2C_New_South_Wales%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Flabel%20%20.%20%20FILTER%28LANGMATCHES%28LANG%28%3Flabel%29%2C%20%22en%22%29%29%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%7BOPTIONAL%7Bdbr%3AEraring%2C_New_South_Wales%20dbo%3Acountry%20%3Fcountry%7D%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%7BOPTIONAL%7Bdbr%3AEraring%2C_New_South_Wales%20dbo%3AisPartOf%20%3FisPartOf%7D%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%7BOPTIONAL%7Bdbr%3AEraring%2C_New_South_Wales%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Flinguistics%2Fgold%2Fhypernym%3E%20%3F_type%7D%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%7BOPTIONAL%7Bdbr%3AEraring%2C_New_South_Wales%20dbo%3Acapital%20%3Fcapital%7D%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%7BOPTIONAL%7Bdbr%3AEraring%2C_New_South_Wales%20dbo%3AlargestCity%20%3Flcity%7D%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNION%7BOPTIONAL%7Bdbr%3AEraring%2C_New_South_Wales%20grs%3Apoint%20%3Fgeopoint%7D%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)

Comment: you can't use a comma like in  `dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales` - prefixed URIs have some restrictions on the syntax. Use the full URI here instead.

Comment: by the way, your query is weird. Why the `UNION`?

Comment: (omitted prefixes here): `SELECT ?label ?country ?isPartOf ?_type ?capital ?lcity ?geopoint
WHERE { VALUES ?s {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eraring,_New_South_Wales>}
        ?s rdfs:label ?label  .  
        FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), "en"))
        OPTIONAL{?s dbo:country ?country} 
        OPTIONAL{?s dbo:isPartOf ?isPartOf}
        OPTIONAL{?s <http://purl.org/linguistics/gold/hypernym> ?_type}
        OPTIONAL{?s dbo:capital ?capital}
        OPTIONAL{?s dbo:largestCity ?lcity}
        OPTIONAL{?s grs:point ?geopoint}
  }`

Comment: They can be escaped: `dbr:Eraring\,_New_South_Wales`

Comment: @AndyS I know this, but not on DBpedia ... try `select * {dbr:Eraring\,_New_South_Wales ?p ?o}` -> `Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 0: Bad character '\' (0x5c) in SPARQL expression at '\'`. But ok, I see that my initial statement was too generic.

Comment: @AKSW can you turn this into an answer?

Comment: @AndyS dbr:Eraring\,_New_South_Wales does not work. Tried it.

Comment: @AKSW thanks for the ans, its working **<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eraring,_New_South_Wales>**

Comment: Some useful links for this issue: - https://github.com/RDFLib/sparqlwrapper/issues/94 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338506/handling-commas-when-using-a-namespace-prefix-in-a-sparql-where-clause - https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/318

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use prefixed names in your query and the error message indicates

```
dbr:Eraring,_New_South_Wales
```

as the source of error, in particular the comma makes the parser fail.

So let's have a look at the W3C recommendation:

> 4.1.1.1 Prefixed Names
>
> The PREFIX keyword associates a prefix label with an IRI. A prefixed
>   name is a prefix label and a local part, separated by a colon ":". A
>   prefixed name is mapped to an IRI by concatenating the IRI associated
>   with the prefix and the local part. The prefix label or the local part
>   may be empty. Note that SPARQL local names allow leading digits while
>   XML local names do not. SPARQL local names also allow the
>   non-alphanumeric characters allowed in IRIs via backslash character
>   escapes (e.g. ns:id\=123). SPARQL local names have more syntactic
>   restrictions than CURIEs.

Given that the error occurs in the local name and comma is a non-alphanumeric character, the most important part here is

> SPARQL local names also allow the non-alphanumeric characters allowed
>   in IRIs **via backslash character escapes** (e.g. ns:id\=123).

That means, we can use the comma but have to escape it via `\`, i.e. we have to write

```
dbr:Eraring\,_New_South_Wales
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the Virtuoso parser has some issues with it (or I'm doing something wrong there) given that a query like

```sql
SELECT * { dbr:Eraring\,_New_South_Wales ?p ?o }
```

fails with

```
Virtuoso 37000 Error SP030: SPARQL compiler, line 0: Bad character '\' (0x5c) in SPARQL expression at '\'
```

An option that always works is indeed to just use the full IRI.

A query that works on the DBpedia endpoint is

```sql
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX grs: <http://www.georss.org/georss/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

SELECT ?label ?country ?isPartOf ?_type ?capital ?lcity ?geopoint WHERE {
 VALUES ?s {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Eraring,_New_South_Wales>} 
 ?s rdfs:label ?label . 
 FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?label), "en")) 
 OPTIONAL{?s dbo:country ?country} 
 OPTIONAL{?s dbo:isPartOf ?isPartOf} 
 OPTIONAL{?s <http://purl.org/linguistics/gold/hypernym> ?_type} 
 OPTIONAL{?s dbo:capital ?capital} 
 OPTIONAL{?s dbo:largestCity ?lcity} 
 OPTIONAL{?s grs:point ?geopoint} 
}
```

You can see that I modified the query a bit:

- there is no need for the `UNION` clauses – all you want is to get
  optional data if exist, so `OPTIONAL` is the correct SPARQL feature
- I used `VALUES` keyword for inline data